# Как открыть свёрнутую панель задач мышью, если окно без границ развёрнуто на весь экран

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Было реализовано переопределение стиля окна на WPF, чтобы добавить меню в заголовок.

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome
                NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                GlassFrameThickness="0"
                ResizeBorderThickness="7" 
                CornerRadius="0"
                CaptionHeight="50"
            />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border x:Name="PART_Container" Padding="0">
                    <Grid
                        TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
                        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="PART_Border"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Background="#EFEFF2"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlBorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{StaticResource BaseBorderThickness}"
                            Padding="0">
                            <DockPanel
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="TitleBar"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                    BorderThickness="0">
                                    <Grid MinHeight="36">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="34"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="34"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="34"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle 
                                            Fill="{StaticResource LogoDrawingBrush}"
                                            x:Name="Icon"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Margin="4,6,4,0"
                                            Width="32"
                                            Height="32"
                                            MouseUp="IconMouseUp"
                                            MouseLeftButtonDown="IconMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock
                                                x:Name="Caption"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                Margin="6,2,0,2" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlock}"
                                                Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            <Menu Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Background="{x:Null}">
                                                <MenuItem Header="Settings" Command="{Binding OpenSettingsCommand}" />
                                                <MenuItem Header="Profile">
                                                    <MenuItem Header="Load" Command="{Binding Path=LoadProfileCommand}"/>
                                                    <MenuItem Header="Set To Default" Command="{Binding Path=SetToDefaultProfileCommand}"/>
                                                </MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Open Logs Folder" Command="{Binding OpenLogsFolderCommand}"/>
                                            </Menu>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Button
                                            x:Name="MinButton"
                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Width="34"
                                            Height="26"
                                            Click="MinButtonClick"
                                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                            <Grid MaxHeight="9" MaxWidth="9">
                                                <Path
                                                    Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}"
                                                    StrokeThickness="1"
                                                    Stretch="None"
                                                    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                                    Data="M0,8 H8 M0,7 H8 M0,6 H8"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button
                                            Grid.Column="3"
                                            x:Name="MaxButton" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Width="34"
                                            Height="26"
                                            Click="MaxButtonClick"
                                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                            <Grid MaxHeight="9" MaxWidth="9">
                                                <Path
                                                    x:Name="PART_MaxButton_Path"
                                                    Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}"
                                                    StrokeThickness="1"
                                                    Stretch="None"
                                                    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                                    Data="M0,0 H8 V8 H0 V0 M0,1 H8 M0,2 H8"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button
                                            Grid.Column="4"
                                            x:Name="CloseButton" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Width="34"
                                            Height="26"
                                            Click="CloseButtonClick"
                                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                            <Grid MaxHeight="9" MaxWidth="9">
                                                <Path
                                                    Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}"
                                                    StrokeThickness="1.5"
                                                    Stretch="None"
                                                    Data="M0,0 L8,8 M0,8 L8,0"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_MaxButton_Path" Property="Data" Value="M0,3 H5 V8 H0 V3 M0,4 H5 M3,0 H8 V5 H7 M3,1 H8"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource VS2012WindowBorderBrushInactive}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

В результате, при максимизации окна, оно перекрывает полосочку свёрнутой панели задач. При подведении мышки к краю экрана панель задач не всплывает.
Помогите вернуть данную функциональность.

Для воспроизведения понадобится этот код:

```
internal static class LocalExtensions
{
    public static void ForWindowFromTemplate(this object templateFrameworkElement, Action<Window> action)
    {
        Window window = ((FrameworkElement)templateFrameworkElement).TemplatedParent as Window;
        if (window != null) action(window);
    }
}

public partial class WindowStyle
{
    void IconMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount > 1)
            sender.ForWindowFromTemplate(w => SystemCommands.CloseWindow(w));
    }

    void IconMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        //TODO Неправильно получаются координаты появления меню при масштабировании, надо найти причину
        var point = element.PointToScreen(new Point(element.ActualWidth / 2, element.ActualHeight / 2 ));
        sender.ForWindowFromTemplate(w => SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenu(w, point));
    }

    void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Window)sender).StateChanged += WindowStateChanged;
        WindowStateChanged(sender,null);
    }

    void WindowStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var w = ((Window)sender);
        var containerBorder = (Border)w.Template.FindName("PART_Container", w);
        if (w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            containerBorder.Padding = new Thickness(7);
        }
        else
        {
            containerBorder.Padding = new Thickness(0);
        }
    }

    void CloseButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sender.ForWindowFromTemplate(SystemCommands.CloseWindow);
    }

    void MinButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sender.ForWindowFromTemplate(SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow);
    }

    void MaxButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sender.ForWindowFromTemplate(w =>
        {
            if (w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(w);
            else 
                SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(w);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А что у вас на данный момент в качестве шаблона?

Comment: @VlaD, я добавил шаблон.

Comment: Хм. Судя по всему, проблемы с настройками WindowChrome. Я попробую воспроизвести на работе.